# Makefile include .env conflicts with MAKEFILE_LIST

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile where I want to load environment variables placed in  `.env` file.

I am using the `include` directive to achieve this.

```
-include .env
```

I also have an `help` target to display the available tasks:

```
help: ## Displays help menu
    grep -E '^[a-zA-Z_-]+:.*?## .*$$' $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | sort | awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":.*?## "}; {printf "\033[36m%-30s\033[0m %s\n", $$1, $$2}'
```

The problem is that when using together with the include directive, it doesnt work correctly. The help task just shows "Makefile" as name for all the targets.

The `$(MAKEFILE_LIST)` returns "Makefile, .env" instead of the target names, so I guess it became messed up with the .env somehow.

I don´t know enough about Makefiles to understand what´s wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanks you.

Comment: Maybe reading the docs on `MAKEFILE_LIST` will help understand the problem? https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html#index-MAKEFILE_005fLIST-_0028list-of-parsed-makefiles_0029

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Solution

Update your `help` target to leverage `$(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))` instead of just `$(MAKEFILE_LIST)` so that `grep` is targeting the correct file before it pipes the targets with `##` comments.

```
help: ## Displays help menu
    grep -E '^[a-zA-Z_-]+:.*?## .*$$' $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) | sort | awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":.*?## "}; {printf "\033[36m%-30s\033[0m %s\n", $$1, $$2}'
```

### Explanation

The original behavior of the `$MAKEFILE_LIST` variable is to output `Makefile` rather than a list of the Makefile's that are being included. So after your include, it's appending the name to the list. So you see what you mentioned `Makefile, .env`. The `grep` command that you posted for the `help` target is taking `$MAKEFILE_LIST` and grepping `.env` along with `Makefile`. Since that pattern for comment / help messages doesn't match anything in `.env` there isn't any output, but the `Makefile` does contain matches. This leads `grep` to prepend the `FILENAME` in which it found things in. In this case, `Makefile`. The `awk` command then rips everything before `##`  and strips them to a `:` colon, which grep added and it reads that as the target rather than what the target is in your `Makefile`. So all your help output has the correct comment but the wrong target. You can verify the behavior by running the following grep command in the directory where both these files exist:

```
grep -E '^[a-zA-Z_-]+:.*?## .*$$' Makefile .env
```

Comment: Worked like a charm for me. Thanks!